# Using indicator function on text data set

Tags: r

I have a data set which has three columns:

```
TeamName. Location. Time.
```

Where:
    TeamName: Manchester, Chelsea, Arsenal. 
    Location: Home, Away.

Using indicator function I want to create a vector, where 1 will correspond to: 
`TeamName=='Manchester' & Location=='Home'` , and 0 otherwise.

I looked at some other examples on the web, but they all worked with numbers, not text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
df$index <- df$TeamName == 'Manchester' & df$Location == 'Home'
```

This would actually generate a logical vector with true/false, which however might be enough for you needs.  If you really need 0 and 1, then you could convert using `as.integer` or `as.numeric`.

Comment: Oh, I had to use "&" rather than "," and didn't know that. Thank you very much, works perfectly now!